# Audio sending via Telegram Bot seems like document

Tags: api, audio, telegram-bot

I'm building a telegram bot. When i try to send audio using the [sendAudio](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendaudio) method it sends like a downloadable file instead of music(playing in audio player etc.).

Example of what i send:

```
{"title":"Blabla","performer":"Blabla","audio":"SOME_FILE_ID"}
```

If I don't send title and performer it sends like a voice record.
If I send title and performer it sends like a document.
But I need to send it like a music.

Comment: what is yout file mime_type?